# If and statement in jquery on drupal 6

Tags: jquery, drupal-6

I know I'm not doing this right but any help would be appreciated. You can fine a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dz71dyjd/

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
if($(".cart-block-item-title").contains("volume dealer")) && $('.cart-block-summary-total .uc-price').val < 5,000 {
alert ('order minimum not met')
```

}

I ultimately want this code to run on a click to prevent customers going to checkout if they don't meet order minimums.

Comment: Are you sure $('.uc-price).val returns a correct value?

Comment: No. That's part of what I need help on... I haven't been doing code like this in like three years so I'm pretty rusty :(

Comment: Try to assign an ID to that label and then access the inner text.
If I'm right in JS it should be something like document.getElementByID("yourID").innerHTML or with Jquery $('#yourID').html()

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out yesterday. It took a few steps. Here is the code:

```
    var DealerVar = $('.cart-block-item-title a').attr('href')
var cartTotal = $(".cart-block-summary-total > span").text().replace(',', '').replace('$', '');
var DealerVar2 = DealerVar.split('/');
var DealerVar3 = DealerVar2[1]

if (DealerVar3 == "dealers") {


if (cartTotal < 500.00)  
{
$('.cart-block-checkout, #edit-checkout').click(function(){
    alert ('In order to check out you need to have the minimum order amount in your cart for your pricing tier ($500). Please add more items to your cart.');
    return false 
});
}             
}

var VolDealVar = $('.cart-block-item-title a').attr('href')
var cartTotal = $(".cart-block-summary-total > span").text().replace(',', '').replace('$', '');
var VolDealVar2 = VolDealVar.split('/');
var VolDealVar3 = VolDealVar2[1]

if (VolDealVar3 == "volume-dealers") {


if (cartTotal < 2000.00)  
{
$('.cart-block-checkout, #edit-checkout').click(function(){
    alert ('In order to check out you need to have the minimum order amount in your cart for your pricing tier ($2,000). Please add more items to your cart.');
    return false 
});
}             
}

var DistributorVar = $('.cart-block-item-title a').attr('href')
var cartTotal = $(".cart-block-summary-total > span").text().replace(',', '').replace('$', '');
var DistributorVar2 = DistributorVar.split('/');
var DistributorVar3 = DistributorVar2[1]

if (DistributorVar3 == "distributors") {


if (cartTotal < 6000.00)  
{
$('.cart-block-checkout, #edit-checkout').click(function(){
    alert ('In order to check out you need to have the minimum order amount in your cart for your pricing tier ($6,000). Please add more items to your cart.');
    return false 
});
}             
}
var VolDistributorVar = $('.cart-block-item-title a').attr('href')
var cartTotal = $(".cart-block-summary-total > span").text().replace(',', '').replace('$', '');
var VolDistributorVar2 = VolDistributorVar.split('/');
var VolDistributorVar3 = VolDistributorVar2[1]

if (VolDistributorVar3 == "volume-distributors") {


if (cartTotal < 10000.00)  
{
$('.cart-block-checkout, #edit-checkout').click(function(){
    alert ('In order to check out you need to have the minimum order amount in your cart for your pricing tier ($10,000). Please add more items to your cart.');
    return false 
});
}             
}
```